# Pi is not being treated as numeric by NumberQ in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The current documentation says that Pi will be treated as numeric by NumberQ

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pi.html

But consider this list:

```
In[146]:= myList = {a, b, Sin[x], 10, 20, Pi, 1/2, 0.345}

Out[146]= {a, b, Sin[x], 10, 20, \[Pi], 1/2, 0.345}
```

If I do this (below), NumberQ returns False:

```
In[158]:= NumberQ @myList[[6]]

Out[158]= False
```

Why?

How would you "pipe" the list to a testing expression so that it returns Pi ?

For example, if I use

```
In[148]:= myList // Cases[_Real]

Out[148]= {0.345}
```

How can I uses Cases to make it return Pi ?

TIA,
Hank

Comment: The documentation says NumericQ, not NumberQ; NumberQ treats it as a constant, not a number.

Comment: OMG, you are totally right! Thanks! In[162]:= NumericQ@myList[[6]]

Out[162]= True. But myList // Cases[NumericQ] still yields an empty list {}. What am I doing wrong here with Cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
Cases[myList, _?NumericQ]
```

or, with fuller syntax for more complex cases

```
Cases[myList, _?(NumericQ[#] &)]
```

or

```
Select[myList, NumericQ]
```

Comment: ```In[187]:= myList // Select[# ==  Pi &]

Out[187]= {\[Pi]}```

Comment: `myList // Select @ NumericQ`

Answer (score 0):

If I do:

```
In[156]:= Head[\[CapitalPi]]

Out[156]= Symbol
```

I see that Pi is a Symbol. This means that the following expression with Cases will (kinda) work:

```
In[160]:= myList // Cases[_Symbol]

Out[160]= {a, b, \[Pi]}
```

That shows me I can get to Pi (but not *only* Pi). So that's a clue I'm on the right track.
However, the documentation is still confusing to me (regarding NumberQ treating Pi as numeric).

Comment: `myList // Cases[_?NumericQ]`